# Rendering ajax layout from cake's beforeFilter using requestAction

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I have a scenario were in the beforeFilter in AppController, I have a session-check method which checks if some session data is set. If not, the user is redirected to the login page.

This works well with server side action call, however when ajax calls are made, the beforeFilter seems to ignore the requestAction.. Here's my code

**`AppController beforeFilter`**

```
public function beforeFilter(){
  if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
     echo $this->requestAction("/users/ajax_login", array('return'));
  }else{
     $this->redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

**`ajax_login action`**

```
function ajax_login() {
    $this->render('ajax_login', 'ajax');
}
```

**`ajax_login view`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = '<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$html->url('/login').'"'; ?>';
</script>;
```

Basically this should render an ajax layout. However the view is not being rendered and therefore redirection is not working.

Of course I get an error since the action being called via ajax is still being called which fires an error  `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` due to session expiry.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution that works. Here's the code :

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Auth', 'RequestHandler');

    function beforeFilter() {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            if(!$this->Session->check('data')) {
                header('Requires-Auth: 1'); // set header and make sure to exit
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just have a jquery (acaxComplete) event listener in place which checks for the header, if it is set to 1, redirect to login page.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
        var requiresAuth;
        try { requiresAuth = request.getResponseHeader('Requires-Auth') }
        catch(e) {}

        if (requiresAuth == 1) {
            window.location = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); ?>";
            return false;
        }
    });
   });
</script>
```

This works fine. However I am still interested as to why my first solution did not work. Any input is welcome.. Cheers